# Swift UIKit integrate side menu to existing app

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, side-menu

i am struggling to add a side menu to my already existing app.
i've read all kinds of tutorials, but almost each and everyone of them uses a container ViewController, which I'd try to avoid to use..

I got a single page app, with thousand of code rows, embedded into a navigation controller (for a additional settings page)
I've added a UIBarbuttonItem on the top left to toggle the visibility of the menu.

now I created the side menu in a different ViewController on the Storyboard / InterfaceBuilder, and just can't find a way to easily slide that ViewController in from the left side.

one approach was to create single view behind my app and push the main view aside to reveal that view, but the result was not as sexy as I wanted it to be, and designing a view in the background of another view would not be that easy to work with too...

I'd just use a container View Controller if I absolutly have to, and I don't want to use any cocoa pods...
does anyone know how to proceed? any push in the right direction'd be greatly appreciated!